# Why is my query returning the wrong string type?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, firebird, dbexpress

According to [the official Firebird documentation](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/migration-mssql-data-types.html), columns containing Unicode strings (what SQL Server calls NVARCHAR) should be declared as `VARCHAR(x) CHARACTER SET UNICODE_FSS`.  So I did that, but when I query the table with DBExpress, the result I get back is a TStringField, which is AnsiString only, not the TWideStringField I was expecting.

How do I get DBX to give me a Unicode string result from a Unicode string column?

Comment: Don't know the fb driver, but with the ib driver (on a fb database) I was able to work with UTF8 columns with a param of 'ServerCharSet = UTF8' on the sql connection. For a connection, it was possible to work either with unicode or with ansi, I mean I wasn't able to work with tables with mixed columns. Don't know if it is still the case..

Comment: BTW, if you're designing the database don't work with UNICODE_FSS. The first hit on google for "UNICODE_FSS" is [this](http://www.destructor.de/firebird/charsets.htm).

Comment: @sertac: Good catch.  I'm generating the create script programatically, so I can fix that up easily enough.  Still doesn't solve the TWideStringField issue, though...

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302670/delphi-dbexpress-and-interbase-utf8-migration-steps-and-risks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With Firebird, your only option is to set the whole database connection to a Unicode char set, for example to utf8.

That way, all the VarChar columns will result in fields of type TWideStringField.  The fields will be always TWideStringFields despite the particular char set declared when creating the column.

[image: Char set at connection level]

Setting this, will result in this:

[image: TWideStringField]

I collect this images now from a example project I created while teaching Delphi a few months ago.  You have to set this property before creating any persistent fields if that's your case.

It looks like the driver does not support the UNICODE_FSS charset, as my first action was to create a new project, set the property and then create some fields. IMHO it's better to declare the whole database as utf8 or other charset supported by the driver in the create database sentence, and then match the database charset in Delphi to avoid string conversions.